# Align Image View without stopping a stackView auto-resizing

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-autolayout

I am currently facing an issue where I have a horizontal stack view with a UILabel and a ImageView. I am needing the stackView to dynamically change height depending on how many lines of text there is. I am also wanting the imageView to be aligned with the bottom of the UILabel(even when there is a second line).

[image]

I have currently tried:

- Adding a UIView and aligning the ImageView in it. This stops the stackView auto-resizing.
- Changing the Content Mode to bottom doesn't work either as I am wanting aspect fit.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Do you want the imageView to look like it does in your picture? So it it centered vertically? Or, do you really want the "heart" in the image to be at the bottom-right corner? Are you doing this via code? Is this a table view cell prototype?

Comment: @DonMag I want it to be in the bottom right corner. This is a view cell prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get your desired result pretty easily.

Constrain your Stack View to all 4 sides, using however much top/bottom and left/right "padding" you want.

Give your Image View a Width constraint (I'm guessing you want it around 24), and an Aspect Ratio of 1:1. That will keep it from stretching vertically. `Content Mode: Aspect Fit`

Set your Stack View properties to:

[image]

And... you should be all set.